How to add loader in mat-table in angular
Code:
 <table  mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="table table-responsive">
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
                 
                   
                  <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
                    <td class="mat-cell" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
                      No data to dislay.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

here i added this for empty data but is there any functionality for loading ??
i am getting that data from api so its take some time. if response data is empty then my above code work fine but i want same thing with loader

Your question isnt too clear, plus you need to provide your component function i.e your_component.ts file what have you tried?

do you want a spinner why you await data? or what exactly is the loader?

I would assume nothing, since the context of loader isnt clear.
first you will have to modify your.ts file. Although you would have to change the datatype "any" to the desired type
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, catchError, map, startWith } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  data$: Observable<any[]> = of([]);
  loading$: Observable<boolean> = of(true);

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = this.http.get<any[]>('your-api-endpoint').pipe(
      map(data => {
        this.loading$ = of(false);
        return data;
      }),
      startWith([]), // Emits an empty array initially
      catchError(() => {
        this.loading$ = of(false);
        return of([]);
      })
    );
  }
}

Then you will have to update your html file with this.
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="data$ | async" matSort class="table table-responsive">
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  <!-- Loader Row -->
  <tr *ngIf="(loading$ | async)" class="mat-row">
    <td class="mat-cell" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length" class="loading-cell">
      <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <!-- No Data Row -->
  <tr *ngIf="!(loading$ | async) && (data$ | async)?.length === 0" class="mat-row">
    <td class="mat-cell" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
      No data to display.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

You can use this code as an alterate for putting the spinner in the table.
</td>
<td class="mat-cell" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length" *ngIf="isLoading">
<mat-spinner diameter="50"></mat-spinner>
</td>
</tr>

// this is an extra if you want to style the container with css
.loader-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}


here in this case loader is display  instead  of  table but i want to display loader  inside the table like 'no data found' message

if my array is empty then i am displaying 'no data to display'


        No data to display.
      

like this
i also tried  this way but its not working . you can see there is one directive *matNoDataRow its only applicable if you get empty array in [dataSource] but in my case i am calling one api and its give data after some time so till then i want to display loader. but there is no  specific  directive  for loader

 this part is already working i have problem with how to place loader inside the table while api give the data
just put this <mat-spinner></mat-spinner> inside where ever your table is.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I'm guessing that you want to add a spinner while the data is being fetched from the API.
Since you are using Material, I would suggest using the progress spinner.

You should import the module

import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';

then add it to the part of your html where you want the spinner



source: https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview
